# How do I host a static website on a gcs bucket inside a vpc?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-vpc

AWS makes this possible with private link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html

I want to do this with gcs

I have a static html site I want to host on a gcs bucket

BUT I want this to be hosted inside a vpc and use GCP VPC firewall rules to control access

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Storage is hosted outside your VPC. You can't set firewall rules to access it.

However, to serve static files on internet, you can [put your files on Cloud Storage, create a Global HTTPS load balancer and define your bucket as backend](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website).

You can also serve your static file through [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/serving-static-files) and use the [App Engine firewall feature](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls) to achieve something similar to your requirements.

Comment: This is using google's layer 7 application load balancer? How do I restrict access? Can it use a cloud armor policy?

Comment: Yes, it use Google Cloud Load balancer on OSI layer 7. You can use Cloud Armor to filter IPs and IAP to restrict access to authenticated account  and the correct IAM authorization.

Comment: I unmarked this as the answer after reading that doc. It requires you to "To make all objects in your bucket readable to everyone on the public internet". Which defeats the purpose of a cloud armor policy for restricting access

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that this is not currently a possibility. There is an [ongoing Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/63068776) that you might find useful, as there are other customers trying to achieve your exact setup.

[Access control in Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control) is based on IAM permissions and ACLs, and they are not IP based in a way where you could make use of [VPC Firewall Rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls).

Nonetheless, I believe that the approach that currently will be most suitable to achieve the desired behavior will be to use [VPC Service Controls](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/overview), where you could define a service perimeter around `storage.googleapis.com` (notice that you won't be able to define the perimeter to an individual bucket, but to the whole service, meaning all the buckets within that project) and take advantage of this feature. Although, notice that it has [certain limitations](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/supported-products#table_storage).

Strict VPC Firewall rules won't apply within this setup, but you could define [access levels](https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/create-basic-access-level) to allow access to your buckets from outside the perimeter. Such levels are based on different conditions, such as IP address or user and service accounts. However, you cannot block the access to certain ports as you could with VPC Firewall rules.